# Fragment with thread causes lag in Main UI

Tags: android, multithreading, android-fragments

I am using 4 fragments in my `main.xml`. Each fragment runs seperate thread continuously to plot dynamic graph.I have an `EditText` in `main.xml`.`EditText` keyboard lags when a key is entered.I am using Android Plot graph jar.My main thread UI seems blocking, please help.Can threads be used in fragments?

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white" >
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:hint="@string/name" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/Data"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/name" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/FirstFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        class="com.lnt.apms.activities.FirstFragmentActivity" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/SecondFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/FirstFragment"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        class="com.lnt.apms.activities.SecondFragmentActivity" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/ThirdFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/SecondFragment"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        class="com.lnt.apms.activities.ThirdFragmentActivity" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/FourthFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/ThirdFragment"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        class="com.lnt.apms.activities.FourthFragmentActivity" />

      </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

FragmentActivity.java

```
public class FragmentActivity extends Fragment{




  public FragmentActivity() {


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

   plotGraph(.....);//function call


}



void plotGraph(final XYCoordinates Series1,final XYCoordinates Series2,final double[] tempEcg) {

    Thread thread = new Thread() {



        XYCoordinates seriesA = Series1;
        XYCoordinates seriesB = Series2;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            runFlag = true;

            try {

                while (runFlag) {

                    synchronized (seriesA) {

                      //code to process graph.


                        notifier.notifyObservers();//have defined this 
                    }

                    Thread.sleep(3);

                }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    };
    thread.start();


}
```

}

Comment: Place a Runnable within Thread, don't do heavy operations in Thread.run()

Comment: @ Marek Sebera Can you please give a sample code.Since operation is heavy I am using threads

Comment: I tried    new Thread(new Runnable() { public void run() {}         }).start(); but still it hangs :(

Comment: Try running it within async handler, use android.os.Handler.postDelayed(Runnable, long), but if that what you tried doesn't work, I suspect problem within creating your graphs, than in your activity structure

Comment: Graph slows down with `handler` so I tried Thread with while(true).With thread graph is fast but Main UI lags

Comment: Write a manager for your chart that uses a asynctask to draw the chart in the background and update as soon as its done. You can then run your updates asynchronously to update faster. You will have to manage the amount of current processes though to avoid out of memory errors.

Comment: @Neil I tried using AsyncTAsk, but since its heavy only one fragment is showing graph using aynctask. I used While(true) loop within doInBackground and i am redrawing graph in publish progress function.Please help am I making any mistake here?

Comment: The Thread with the while loop in is your problem. If you use AsyncTask correctly you should not have problems. I use AsyncTasks for my chart but only for drawing. I update my image on the main ui thread.

Comment: @Neil I am still not getting how to manage my code without while loop..I tried other methods(like handler), but graph plotting was slow with fragments working correctly.